# How to connect mysql to PHP through largon

Tags: php, mysql, laragon

I am trying to do some coursework, where I have to create a webpage that interacts with a mySQL database using PHP.

I am unfamiliar with PHP and I don't know how to connect an SQL database to it.

I have access to a piece of software called "laragon", which seems to be a virtual server program.

So far, I have managed to get a "hello world program" to run.

```
<HTML><BODY>Test.<br>

<?php echo "PHP test"?>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Result:

[image: <code><HTML><BODY>Test.<br>PHP test</BODY></HTML></code>]

I have been trying to find out how to "connect" PHP to a mySql database through Google, but I could not find anything that clearly shows how to do so. I tried adapting some code I found from https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/php-mysql-connect/.

```
<HTML><BODY>Test.<br>

<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "DDL.sql");
if ($conn->connect_error)
{die("ERROR: Unable to connect: " . $conn->connect_error);} 
echo 'Connected to the database.<br>';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM user");
echo "Number of rows: $result->num_rows";
$result->close();
$conn->close();
?>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Result:

[image: A screenshot, showing an error message: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ddl.sql'"]

`DDL.sql` is a file created using notepad. It contains 5 DDL create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists USER (id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
...)

CREATE TABLE if not exists COMMUNITY (id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
style TEXT)

etc.
```

I opened the largon terminal and opened mySQL in it. The error seems to be a problem with *user access rights*, so I tried adapting some code that I found in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mpQts3ezPVg?t=145), and entering it into the laragon terminal.

```
C:\largon\www>cd ..\bin\mysql\mysql-5.1.72-win32\bin

C:\largon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.1.72-win32\bin>mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.1.72-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> GRANT * ON DDL.sql
    -> TO 'USR'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ON DDL.sql
TO 'USR'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'' at line 1
mysql> GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON DDL.sql
   -> TO 'USR'@'localhost'
   -> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'ddl.sql' doesn't exist
mysql> GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON DDL
    -> TO 'USR'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
mysql> GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON DDL.*
    -> TO 'USR'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

It seems like I have to create a username and password. I then added the name and password to my adapted PHP test code.

```
<HTML><BODY>Test.<br>

<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USR", "pass", "DDL.sql");
if ($conn->connect_error)
{die("ERROR: Unable to connect: " . $conn->connect_error);} 
echo 'Connected to the database.<br>';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM user");
echo "Number of rows: $result->num_rows";
$result->close();
$conn->close();
?>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Result:

[image: A screenshot, showing an error message: Unable to connect: Access denied for user 'USR'@'localhost' to database 'ddl.sql']

I am currently trying to get a test PHP page to run, so that I can work out how to create a PHP page that accesses a mySQL database.

How do I access a mySQL database using PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL connect on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507230/mysql-connect-on-php)

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO It doesn't seem to say anything about creating the user and password in Laragon.

Comment: But it does about accessing a mySQL database using PHP? But i think yout errors are about mysql user settings What is your Mysql default user ? root ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO I have tried adapting the code in the top answer of that question, and it just gives me the following error: `Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ddl'`

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO How do I check my mySQL default user?